# How to load a second view controller with a swipe gesture?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have a Tabbed Based application and I want to use swipe gestures to navigate through the view controllers.
I tried:

```
    - (IBAction)swipeLeftDetected:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
UISecondViewController *second =[[UISecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UISecondViewController" bundle:nil];
second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];

}
```

paired with this:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad; {
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftDetected:)];
swipeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];

}
```

But it crashes on the swipe. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works well on my Xcode.
Only changed:

```
UISecondViewController *second =[[UISecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UISecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

to:

```
SecondViewController *second =[[SecondViewController alloc] init];
```

because I don't have the UISecondViewController class.
Just verify there is UISecondViewController.xib in your project, otherwise it will crash.
But I'm not sure here is your problem.